# Getter is used to add value in dynamoDB

Tags: java, set, amazon-dynamodb, crud, getter-setter

I have an attribute called Attribute which is Set in dynamoDB(not mandatory), all the values for the attributes will be sent through an api which will be added into dynamoDB. I am using

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributename = Attribute)
private set<String> Attribute

public Set<String> getAttribute() {
     if(CollectionUtils.isNullOrEmpty(Attribute)) {
         return ImmutableSet.of(DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE);
     } else {
         return ImmutableSet.copyOf(Attribute);
     }
}

public void setAttribute(final Set<String> Attribute) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNullOrEmpty(Attribute)) {
        this.categories = ImmutableSet.of();
    } else {
        this.categories = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Attribute);
    }
}
```

I am expecting my dynamoDB table to have an empty set when we don't pass in an attribute value in the request we use, but instead of that, it is saving DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE as the value of the field Attribute.

My DynamoDBMapperConfig.Savebehavior has default UPDATE, but I see that while saving a new value all the Savebehavior works the same.

If anyone knows the issue please help me with this, I have been trying to debug this from a long time. I want to know why the value in getAttribute is getting stored as the Attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
private set<String> Attribute

@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.SS)
public Set<String> getAttribute() {
     return Attribute;
}

public void setAttribute(final Set<String> Attribute) {
    this.Attribute = Attribute;
}
```

DynamoDBMapper will handle the String Set for you. You just need to use the right annotation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html

Comment: After trying this, the value thats getting stored in db is taken from getter and not from setter.

Comment: You only apply the annotation to the getters. As long as you follow normal naming conventions the annotation applies both on loading and saving items.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. So, thats why if I provide a default value in getter, that value will be saved in dynamo instead of the value we provide in setter right?

Comment: Any resource for this?